# My dropdown menu will not display the given list items given the following code

Tags: html, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, dropdown

I can't figure out why the dropdown menu will not display the list items given the following code. The dropdown button should display the three list4ed items on a click. I'm using Bootstrap and the css is below as well.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0-beta3/css/all.min.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oxygen:400,300,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <title>Our Menu</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
        <nav id="header-nav" class=" navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar-brand">
                    <div class="pull-left"><h1>Food, LLC</h1></div>
                </div>
                <div class="dropdown">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="menuDropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
                    </button>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="menuDropdown">
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#Chicken">Chicken</a></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#Beef">Beef</a></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#Sushi">Sushi</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
    
    <h1 class="text-center">Our Menu</h1>
    <div id="Box1">
      <h2 class="text-center">Chicken</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      <br>
    </div>
    <div id="Box2">
      <h2 class="text-center">Beef</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      <br>
    </div>
    <div id="Box3">
      <h2 class="text-center">Sushi</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>
        <!-- Include Bootstrap JS and jQuery -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha384-KyZXEAg3QhqLMpG8r+JzVth6+0Z29w5Jw5F0oww5g5Bf5z5F5V5L5u5r5b5C5f5r5U5T5" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-aA5b4CvE3Vd0R7w5a6f5/4xCb5O5r5B5f5B5f5/5C5r5u5r5r5T5f5B5f5B5I5f5U5T5" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

```
body {
    font-size: 16px;
    color: black;
    background-color: white;
    font-family: 'Oxygen', sans-serif;
}

#header-nav {
    background-color: grey;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-width: 10px;
    border-bottom-color: black;

}
h1 {
    margin:30px;
}
h2{
    background-color: grey;
    margin:0;
}
p{
    margin:0;
    background-color: grey;
}
#Box1 p{
    height: 1000px;
}
.dropdown-menu-full {
    width: 100%;
    background-color:blueviolet;
}
```

I've added jQuery and Javascript as others have suggested. I've tried using  instead of  items as well.

Comment: <!-- Include Bootstrap JS and jQuery -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" ></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>  use script like this.

Comment: i don't know what `integrity` and `crossorigin` on the script tag use for, but when i try your code and remove that from the script tag it works.

Answer (score 0):

**For instant solution:** just go to
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/getting-started/introduction/#js
and copy and paste the script tags in your code. You can add them either in the head tag after the body or just before the closing HTML tag.
Like this:

```
...

</body>
    
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.4.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</html>
```

This is the most common issue faced at the start, or at least I've been prone to this,

> our hamburger menu doesn't give us it's menu items ;)

.
Basically, you need to understand that:

- CSS - is responsible for design like colors, padding, etc.
- JS - add dynamicity in our design, like what happens when we click something, etc.
- JQuery - It does most of the things in JS, but some functionalities are supported only by JQuery, like collapsing navbar, alerts, etc.

These are lightweight bundles, that should always be included whenever you are using Bootstrap. Because you never know when you copy/paste or use the bootstrap feature that might be using either JS, Popper, or JQuery. And you end up getting stuck without knowing what's actually being happened here.